# Rest http parametre encoding with value having "=" sign

Tags: c#, rest, soap, encoding

I want to send a request with one of the parameter value having an "=" (equal sign) in it. What's the correct way to encode this request based on the below example.

http://My.base.url?param1=value1&param2=[something=value2]
or
http://My.base.url?param1=value1&param2=[something%3dvalue2]

Comment: Use HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://My.base.url?param1=value1&param2=[something+=+value2]");

Answer (score 0):

```
%3D
```

This is how url encode `=` symbol. [**URL Decoder/Encoder**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)